# Install or Update Visual Web Part in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-server, visual-web-part, visual-studio-2015

I have developed a custom visual web part by using ASP.NET. However, The web part has produced in another server which contains visual studio. I have the .wsp file and I know how to use the SharePoint Power Shell to deploy it. But, there are three different SharePoint Servers in the destination company which includes SharePoint Database, SharePoint Web Server and SharePoint Application Server. Which server should I use to deploy the .wsp file?

Thanks.

Comment: Hello @Mohamed , Your feedback is very important 1. Does the provided answer didn't help you? 2. Do you need any further clarifications? if yes, please comment to the provided answers with your clarifications to can help you or edit your question with clear clarifications, else please Don't forget to **Mark** the correct answer that helped you as accepted to **close this question.** Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Which server should I use to deploy the .wsp file?**

Any SharePoint (Web or APP) Server across the farm that has SharePoint installed, and to avoid the confusion install it on the SharePoint Application Server that hosts the Central Administration.

> **Note:** you can't install it on the DB server because it actually didn't have SharePoint installed!!